# Make a text field highlighted when tabbed to in NetBeans (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jtextfield

I'm trying to make it so when I tab to some text fields on in my JFrame the data in the text field will be highlighted.  I thought I had done this in the properties before but I am not seeing the option now.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [FocusListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) to work out when your field has focus [(tutorial here)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html).

Decide whether you want to *select* the text in the field, or whether you just want to change the background color. It's not quite clear what you mean by *highlight*.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out a few minutes ago... Don't know why I didn't see it before.